# How to use a service to launch a modal (directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular. Not sure what I am missing here and where to start looking.

I need reusable (Twitter Bootstrap) modal dialogues in my application. I have looked at Angular UI, but I want to build them myself - also to be able to understand how it works.

I have:

In my view:

```
<div cng-modal title="Create new user" submit="saveNewUser()">
    <div ng-include=" 'templates/newUserForm.html' "></div>
</div>
```

My directive:

```
UserManagerApp.directive('cngModal', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            title: '@title',
            submit: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/modal.html',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
            $scope.submitHandler = function() {
                $scope.submit();
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element);
        }
    };
});
```

My modal.html template:

```
<div id="newUserModal" class="modal hide" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-action btn-submit" ng-click="submitHandler()"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-action btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And finally (part of) my controller:

```
UserManagerApp.controller('UserManagerCtrl', ['$scope', 'ajaxService', '$route', function($scope, ajaxService, $route) {
    $scope.showNewUserModal = function () {
        $('#newUserModal').modal('show');
    };

    $scope.saveNewUser = function () {
        console.log('saving user');
    };
}]);
```

**THE QUESTION**

Right now I my modal opens because I have given it the ID "newUserModal" in modal.html and in my controller showNewUserModal() triggers to open exactly that modal by its ID.

I want to have a service that I can call from within my controller to construct a new modal as per my directive and open it. Without having to assign any ID. .... How is that possible?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Since you talk about ui-bootstrap. We have there a nice $modal (not  use if you don't want) but to learn how we did it.

Answer (score 1):

In ui-bootstrap's $modal we do something like that in 5 pieces (yours can be simple of course).

We have a stackMap to stack our dialogs (you can have more than 1).

Then we have a directive for the backdrop and a directive for the modal itself.

We have a factory that will prepare a new modal, that is, fetching its template, resolving the resolves it has, creating a controller if needed, a new scope... When it is let's say prepared, we use another factory (it is good to have a factory per purpose) that will create a new backdrop and model by hand like:

```
var angularDomEl = angular.element('<div modal-window></div>');
angularDomEl.attr('window-class', modal.windowClass);
angularDomEl.attr('index', openedWindows.length() - 1);
angularDomEl.attr('animate', 'animate');
angularDomEl.html(modal.content);
var modalDomEl = $compile(angularDomEl)(modal.scope);
```

Then we just need to append it to the body.

So the idea is having a factory that will create by hand the element and configure it and then just append it to the body.

I highly suggest you a deeper reading of the $modal and learn what we did there.